# How to use MongoDB $let in Spring Data MongoOperation

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

MongoDB returns `$count` as an array of single element. And I want to transform it into an object(int or String) so I can map it directly to the `String` field in my class. For that I have used the projection below which do transform it into a `int32` object. Now, I want to translate the below projection to Spring Data `MongoOperation` aggregate

```
{  
  $project:{
  "count": 
    {
      $let:{
        "vars":{
          "elem":
            { $arrayElemAt:["$count",0] }
        },
        "in":{
          "count" :"$$elem.totalVideos"
        }  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Reading the documentation I built part of it as below.

```
Let.define(Let.ExpressionVariable.newVariable("elem").
                    forExpression(ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt.arrayOf("count").elementAt(0)))
```

But not sure if I am doing it right. Does anybody know how this can be done in Spring Data?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

### Pretty implementation

Instead of `"count" :"$$elem.totalVideos"` we apply `"count" : {"$toInt" : "$$elem.totalVideos"}`
You may use [ConvertOperators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ConvertOperators.ToString.html)`.ToString`, [ConvertOperators](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/ConvertOperators.ToString.html)`.ToLong`, etc...

```
Aggregation.project()
    .and(
        Let.define(Let.ExpressionVariable
            .newVariable("elem")
                .forExpression(
                    ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt.arrayOf("count").elementAt(0)
                )
            ).andApply(PropertyExpression.property("count").definedAs(ToInt.toInt("$$elem.totalVideos")))
            //.andApply(ToInt.toInt("$$elem.totalVideos"))
    ).as("count")
```

### Less Pretty implementation

```
Aggregation.project()
    .and(
        Let.define(Let.ExpressionVariable
            .newVariable("elem")
                .forExpression(
                    ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt.arrayOf("count").elementAt(0)
                )
            ).andApply(new AggregationExpression() {
                @Override
                public Document toDocument(AggregationOperationContext context) {
                    return new Document("count", "$$elem.totalVideos");
                }
            })
    ).as("count")
```